# Which Node RPC Binance Smart Chain no rate limit request/sec?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs, rpc, binance-smart-chain

Some rpc nodes Binace Smart Chain are now rate limited to 25-30 requests/sec ..I want to ask where to rent unlimited packages request/sec

Answer (score 0):

I had many issues with limiting rate for BNB smart chain nodes, and i found Chainstack (https://chainstack.com/pricing/). It works just fine for me. The best is to try the free plans and see what works best for your project.